# spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to rename

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I use command:  `mvn package` to package my project, and the pom.xml as follows:

```
<build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass/>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

but it's faild because of `Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to rename 'D:\Code\analysis\server\target\access_server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar' to '
D:\Code\nalysis\server\target\access_server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar.original'`

this exception occurs on windows 10, but it's ok on centos 7.

**counld any one help me solve this problem**

Comment: This could be because of some other process is using that jar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> mvn clean package

or

> mvn clean install

Using clean along with package or install will clear the target directory so the same jar won't overlap at the destination.

package will compile your code and also package it. For example, if your pom says the project is a jar, it will create a jar for you when you package it and put it somewhere in the target directory (by default).

install will compile and package, but it will also put the package in your local repository. This will make it so other projects can refer to it and grab it from your local repository.

Comment: Thanks , but it can not work well. may I should use linux

Comment: mvn command has nothing to do with linux, it will work in both operating systems. When you say it can not work well, what does it mean ?

Comment: Still the problem I said before,  `Unable to rename` the jar package

Comment: seems like you have setup problem, try cleaning the workspace

Answer (score 0):

I my case cmd was open with target folder

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. Easy fix.

In my case, I was trying to run `mvn package` and didn't realise that the application I was trying to package was already running in debug mode. Just figure out which application is using the .jar file and cut it.